# how to always listen keyboard in a uwp app with multiple frame?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, keyboard-events

I did an UWP app in xaml/c# with multiple frame, I want a page in a frame always listen the keyboard inputs but I don't know how to do, can somebody help me ?

I tried KeyDown event in the page in the frame but when I m not focus on this frame the keyboard input listener don't work ...

I want listen *, +, -, 1, 2, 3 ... keys

Comment: Why do you want to listen to the keyboard? Do you want to activate functions in your application like a hotkey?

Comment: How to register a global hotkey for your application in C# (http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/how-to-register-a-global-hotkey-for-your-application-in-c/)

Comment: I want listen *, +, -, 1, 2, 3 ... keys

Comment: Try `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attach to [this event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br208213(v=win.10).aspx):

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated
```

e.g.,

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated +=
    (window, e) =>
    {
        switch (e.VirtualKey)
        {
            case VirtualKey.Number1:
                // ...
                break;
            case VirtualKey.Number2:
                // ...
                break;
            // ...
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much